# Running a Hello World application in Eclipse C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, makefile, mingw

I've just downloaded and put to run Eclipse C++, in Windows, as well as MinGW (I've set its `bin/` directory in the `PATH` variable).

When trying to compile a Hello World program, I get the following error:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project tests ****

(Cannot run program "make" (in directory "D:\lixo\eclipse_cpp\workspace\tests"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Trying to run the `make` command from the command line yielded nothing, so I figured out that MinGW's make was called `MinGW32_make.exe`. I've renamed the file to `make.exe`, but the problem persists.

What am I missing?

Comment: for me it is mingw32-make.exe

Comment: yes, that's how it was here, too.

Comment: im on a 64bits eclipse. could that be an issue?

Comment: I had issues with eclipse cdt using the 64bit version. I decided to switch to 32bit version. I don't know if this will solve your problem though. If you decide to go 32bit you have to download 32bit java too.

Answer (score 1):

Run the 32bit Eclipse instead, and make sure you're running a MinGW toolchain.

Not a solution, but a generally good enough workaround.